# Change values of GridView based on the selected item from a DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

The GridView don't change when i change the value of the dropdown
here is my code :

DropDownList:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td style="height: 49px"><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" >Etablissement</asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td style="height: 49px">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="NOM_ETABL" DataValueField="CD_ETAB" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_TextChanged" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionAREF %>" SelectCommand="getPrescolaireEtablissement" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">          
</asp:GridView>

<div id="footer">
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionAREF %>" SelectCommand="getPreInscriptionPublic" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="CD_ETAB" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="afficher" Type="Boolean" DefaultValue="true" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
</div>
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void DropDownList1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Try using the `SelectedIndexChanged` event instead. I believe it will work better than the `TextChanged` event.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set GridView1.DataSource again, before you call the DataBind method.

Comment: I did not understand your proposal, do you mean :  GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1;

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to call DataBind() on the grid during the postback. Try with just an empty dropdown event receiver.